# Are there good and easy to understand tutorials on NSXMLParser?

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser

I try to wrap my head around NSXMLParser and all its delegate methods. Would be great if someone knew a good tutorial on that. I need an overview that describes the concept and how things are done. I know the seismicXML example from apple but it's really hard to grasp.

I also know there are plenty of other frameworks like TouchXML, but I *want* to understand NSXMLParser. I just want it. I know it's stupid. But I want.

Comment: I can offer nothing specific on NSXMLParser but I'm wondering; what is your existing experience working with XML? DOM vs event driven parsing for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Introduction to Event-Driven XML Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.html) from Apple docs is good enough imo.