# Problems getting an xml feed parsed and loaded into a tableview using delegates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, nsxmlparser, tableview

Very new to programming for iOS and Cocoa so please take it easy on me as I try to wrap my brain around the following. I'm trying to display a tableview populated from an XML feed as the opening screen of my app. I've tried to consume the XML from inside my AppDelegate using the ApplicationDidFinishLaunching method (and then making my AppDelegate a delegate for the XML parser which I access using a NSUrlConnection and its delegate methods) but I can't figure out how to take the parsed XML file and pass it to a tableviewcontroller which can then use it as the datasource for a tableview. When I do try, I always get a blank tableview.

I've written the code a few times and nothing seems to work.. I'll post what I have here to show what I've got so far but I'm afraid its mostly vanilla AppDelegate with a few parser methods thrown in.. any pointers in the right direction would be super appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, probably a bad idea to do the network call in the AppDelegate. Try to put all that code at the view controller level. Here's a brief structure of what I do (Since it's very similar)

- View Controller listens to button events
- Use [`ASIHTTPRequest`](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) to talk to your web service. Handles network really well, you can skip the `NSURLConnection` stuff.
- Try to load your data source (an array?) with static values and see if they come up on the table view.
- Parse the response from `ASIHTTPRequest` using `NSXMLParser`, and load the data you want into the static array you were using. More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138707/are-there-good-and-easy-to-understand-tutorials-on-nsxmlparser).
- Call `[tableView reloadData]` once you're done and the changes will reflect.

Comment: Interesting.. I think that one of my problems is that I don't have tableView set as a property, so I was unable to call reloadData on it. Still mucking around as I am now just crashing whenever I run..

Comment: As it turns out I was displaying my tableView before I had all of my data loaded up and then I wasn't calling reloadData. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify a UITableViewDataSource for your table view and implement the two required methods?

tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
and 
tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

When I get blank tables, this is what it is; I've forgotten to specify the data source